# Limiting factor on Belousov-Zhabotinsky reaction

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, teaching-lab

In the thin film Belousov-Zhabotinsky reactions (popular on Youtube/in chemistry demonstrations), concentric rings of different colors propagate across a petri dish for minutes to hours as the solution oscillates between the forward and reverse reaction.

I can't find an explanation online for why these reactions eventually terminate. Do the components degrade over time into a form that can't continue the reaction? Do they require heat input to continue? Or do they eventually find a non-oscillating equilibrium point because of small imbalances in the quantities of the two reagents?

Finally: is there a way to stage this reaction as a demonstration exhibit that can be restarted indefinitely, by stirring or another simple input, without constantly replenishing the reagents? What conditions would need to be met for this to happen?

(Assuming the potassium bromate/malonic acid version since the reagents are easy to find, but I'm open to other reactions that would be longer lasting)

Comment: Reaction goes forward, just in oscillatory way, with every oscillation it's closer to equilibrium.